# Mask an 2Darray row wise by another array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following 2d array:

```
>>> A = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

>>> b = np.array([1, 2])
```

I would like to get the following mask from A as row wise condition from b as an upper index limit:

```
>>> mask
array([[True, False, False],
       [True, True, False]])
```

Can numpy do this in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array broadcasting:

```
mask = np.arange(A.shape[1]) < b[:,None]
```

output:

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on the idea that the wanted mask corresponds to a boolean lower triangular matrix:

```
mask = np.tril(np.ones(A.shape, dtype=bool))
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```